# Set primary key of a django model to a custom generated string

Tags: python, django, overriding, primary-key, models

I want my model's ID to be set to a hash code that looks something like:

u-timestamp-user_email ---

> example: u-20170330182954email@gmail.com

the user_email part is another field of the same model.

Currently my model looks like this:

```
    def _generateHash():
        return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

# Create your models here

class User(models.Model):
        MANAGER = 'm'
        USER = 'u'

        ROLES = (
                        (MANAGER, 'Manager'), 
                        (USER, 'User'),
                )
        user_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ROLES, null=True)
        hash_code = models.CharField(max_length=500, primary_key=True, default=_generateHash, unique=True, editable=False)

        def save(self):
                self.hash_code = self.role+'-'+self.hash_code+self.user_name
                super(User, self).save()
```

It gets the job done but whenever I update a model instance, instead of updating that certain instance, it creates a new instance. I figured the overriden save() method is the reason for creating the new instance.

Is there a workaround for this to achieve the custom primary key?